# Scala: convert java.sql.Date to org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: java, scala, jodatime, date

I am working in `SCALA` and I have inherited a code using `org.joda.time.DateTime` objects. How can I convert my `java.sql.Date` objects to `org.joda.time.DateTime` objects? Note that I have found many explanations on how to do this in `java` but I am working in `SCALA`

EDIT: works like this for me:

```
val date_String = date.toString
val formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd")
val date_jodatime = formatter.parseDateTime(date_String)
```

Comment: Sounds to me like a simple code translation task. I’m not sure we’re providing such a service on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You should pretty much be able to write the same thing as in Java. Please edit the post to show the Java way so we can help without having to look stuff up.

Comment: @francoisr thank you for your answer but I dont really understand your point. I am coding in `SCALA`here, not `java`. Why would I write in `JAVA`?

Comment: Because Java is a very close relative to Scala, and Java code can usually be straightforwardly translated to Scala. Scala (usually) runs on the JVM, and has built-in Java interop, which makes it able to directly call Java code from Scala. If you provide a working Java implementation, I can take a look at why you're struggling to translate it.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I am very new to both `SCALA` and `JAVA` but I'll try and find a way

Comment: By the way, you are intending to use the wrong types. A `DateTime` in Joda-Time represents a moment, while `java.sql.Date` prestends to represent only a date without a time-of-day and without an offset-from-UTC or time zone. Furthermore, the Joda-Time project is now in maintenance mode, it’s creator Stephen Colebourne having gone on to create its replacement, the *java.time* classes built into Java, defined in JSR 310. [Convert using new methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate()) added to the old classes: `myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate()`

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for the information. Again I have just only inherited the code so I didn't get to choose initially but I will most certainly notify the PO

Answer (score 2):

You can do it implicitly in scala way:

```
//import once, use everywhere
implicit def date2joda(date: java.sql.Date) = ... (put here your java implementation)

val date = new java.sql.Date

//conversion happens implicitly
val dateTime: org.joda.time.DateTime = date
```

Comment: @cchantep The question was how to convert it in Scala. One way is to write the same logic of Java in Scala, or - using a Scala feature - implicit conversion is one of them (didn't say it was the best way to do that..)

Comment: `implicit` is a modifier, nothing prévention to have exactly dame function without, ans si avoid misusages

Answer (score 0):

You could use DateFormatter. Make it into a string and then convert it into JodaTime with that:

```
// You have too get the right pattern too ofc, I just put what I used last time
val dateString = yourDatehere.toString
val dtf = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'CEST' YYYY");
val dateParsed = dtf.parseDateTime(dateString)
```

Also, Java solutions works in Scala. Scala is built on top of JVM.

Comment: Sorry but why wouldn't it be possible to run toString on it? Or are you saying the pattern wouldn't match? Because I wrote in the code, as a comment that the pattern would have to be different (as I just copy pasted something I used). Unless there is a standard date pattern for sql.Date (Which I guess there might be?) you'd have to figure the pattern yourself anyhow.        About LocalDate though, I missed that. I edited it so it's parseDateTime instead. But other than that Pattern I don't see what's wrong with my answer. Could you please tell me?

Comment: Try [the documentation of `java.sql.Date.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toString--): “Formats a date in the date escape format yyyy-mm-dd.” Even with a string that appears to match your pattern, `Thu Apr 11 18:26:40 CEST 2019`, I still get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu Apr 11 18:26:40 CEST 2019"`, I don’t know why.

Comment: And sorry, I was mistaken on one point too: uppercase `YYYY` is correct with Joda-Time (java.time, the modern Java date and time API that I usually use, is different). All in all, formatting to a string and parsing it back still feels like the detour to me, but with your edit I consider your answer correct.

Comment: It's strange that you get that response. For me, this one works for me: Thu May 30 10:27:20 CEST 2019 with that format. Although apparently I made it be DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'CEST' YYYY").  But thanks for the reply. I am using this in production without any issues, so got a bit worried :D

Comment: It’s likely due to different locales. If you want to make sure that your production code works always, specify an English-speaking locale explicitly (or which language is used in your string).

Comment: Actually worked with org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern for me, but that was the kind of answer I was looking for

Comment: Glad you got the help you needed. @Vincent